# Suppress expected warnings and errors in JUnit 5 tests

Tags: logback, junit5, slf4j

I have a library that uses SLF4J and Logback, and some unit tests that cover failure scenarios. My library emits logs at the `WARN` and `ERROR` levels during some of these tests, and these are not useful to folks reviewing the test output, because they are expected.

I would like to suppress the messages that I'm expecting, but still see any other unexpected `WARN` and `ERROR` messages.

Does JUnit 5 / SLF4J / Logback offer any way to achieve this?